# file handling using structured array

Tags: c

I want to store string and char data into a .dat file.. program is running correctly.But after open the .dat file the same name is written twise.Why is that ? I can't find the problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct patients{
        char name[8];
        char appType[1];
};

int main(void)
{

    FILE *F1;
    F1 = fopen("appointment.dat","a");

    int i = 0;
    struct patients detailsArr[5];

    for( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
    {
        printf("Enter Patient Name : ");
        scanf("%s",detailsArr[i].name);

        printf("Enter Appointment Type :");
        scanf(" %c",detailsArr[i].appType);

    }

    if ( F1 == NULL )
    {
        printf("Error in File Reading !");
        return -1;
    }

    for( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
    {
        fprintf(F1 ,"%s\t",detailsArr[i].name);
        fprintf(F1 ,"%s",detailsArr[i].appType);
        fprintf(F1 ,"\n");

    }

    fclose(F1);

    return 0;
}
```

This is my Output :

```
Dilshan CRuwan
Ruwan   TMangala
Mangala SGanesh
Ganesh  CJithen
Jithen  SV
```

Comment: the "SV ~" part is also unwanted part.. it also printing always in my output

Comment: xing : i changed it. But its comes with an error!!!!!!                             
ex2.c:39:17: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
   fprintf(F1 ,"%c",detailsArr[i].appType);
                ~^  ~~~~~~~~~~
                %s

Comment: xing : It worked ! Thanks...... but why we only use array index for appType ... why not for name ?

Comment: xing : OK got it ! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the ancient padded-fixed struct format so these fprintfs are wrong. Should be:

```
fprintf(F1 ,"%.8s\t",detailsArr[i].name);
fprintf(F1 ,"%.1s",detailsArr[i].appType);
```

We should also change the scanf line to

```
scanf("%8s",detailsArr[i].name);
```

so it can actually store all 8.

The reason this fails otherwise is your struct format appears to be non-null-terminated strings when the maximum string size is used. This requires handling as such with printf and scanf format strings, and copying in and out with strncpy. It's kind of awkward code so it's rarely used except for low-level on disk formats.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `%.8s` is not valid scanf.

Comment: @melpomene: I double checked and found you are right. I'm looking up the actual answer now.

Comment: @melpomene: Fixed. it's just %8s.

Comment: @Joshua To avoid having to use `%.8s` in `fprintf` you can use `%7s` in `scanf`.

Comment: @JL2210: Considering he has a `char[1]` I'm pretty sure that is not the correct interpretation.

Comment: @Joshua A `char[1]` is just a pointer to a `char`. That's not very useful, so I just decided to change it to a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line:

```
char appType[1];
```

to this:

```
char appType;
```

if you want to use the `%c` `scanf` format specifier.

To avoid overflow (and non-null-terminated strings), you should also use `%7s` instead of `%s` in this line:

```
 scanf("%s",detailsArr[i].name);
```

You also need to change this line:

```
 fprintf(F1 ,"%s",detailsArr[i].appType);
```

to this:

```
 fprintf(F1 ,"%c",detailsArr[i].appType);
```

It's just a matter of type changes.

Comment: JL2210 : Thanks for the Help!

Comment: @T.MHettiarachchi If this worked for you, you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark below the vote arrows.